# how to remove this comma in the status

Tags: javascript

```
bot.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('ch ')){
        a = message.content
        let str1= a
        let str2= 'ch '
        str3 = str1.split(str2)
        var str4 = str3.toString()
            bot.user.setActivity( { type: 'WATCHING' } , {name:str4} )
    }
})
```

When I type "ch book", it become this :
[image]
a comma in front of the word.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: str3 is an array.  When you call toString on it, it puts in commas.

Comment: `console.log(('ch book').split('ch ').join(''));` <-- this should work for you. `var str4 = str3.join('')`

Comment: Why do you split `str2` just to `join` it on the following line. `toString`ing an array will convert each value to a string and concatenate the using a comma separator

Comment: Welcome to SO, please put your input and expected output, and also please try the post be specific.

Comment: ... and also assign `message.content` to a global variable `a`, and then assign `a` to `str1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are simply trying to remove "ch " from the beginning of the string. You don't need split and arrays for that, you can just use [.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) :

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('ch ')){
        bot.user.setActivity( { type: 'WATCHING' } , { name:message.content.replace('ch ','') })
    }
})
```

Comment: It's very practical to me :D

Comment: The thing is, you did not ask about your actual problem, which was "I want to remove 'ch ' from the beginning of a string". You asked about how to remove an extra comma when joining an array, which was an attempt at solving your actual problem. This was an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). We're used to it on Stackoverflow, because people often ask about what they _belive_ will solve their problem, rather than about the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

#### [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

You should first understand the usage of this method first. This method splits a string into an `array` with each element delimited by the character of your choice, here a comma.

```js
"ch, books".split(','); // returns ["ch", " books"]
```

#### [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

This method returns a string representation of the array, which would have comma-separated elements and you end up going back to square one!

```js
["ch", " books"].toString(); // returns "ch, books"
```

#### Use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) Instead

As long as you need to just **sanitize string** by removing commas or other special characters, use this method along with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```js
"ch, books, copies, notebooks".replace(/,/g, ''); // returns "ch books copies notebooks"

// further remove more characters such as hyphens
"ch, books, copies, note-books".replace(/,|-/g, ''); // returns "ch books copies notebooks"
```